# drawing a texture from an image as game background

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am working on a Cocos2D + Box2D iphone game and have very little experience on this platform.

To detail my issue: I have a list of lines that composite my game ground. I would like to draw  below this lines some texture. How can i draw this from a given image and make sure that the texture is seamless and performance optimal(i.e. the game can be quite long)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the background before anything else. Here mainScene is the CCScene that your CCDirector will use. Cocos2D uses the middle of your image as position.

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"];
background.position = ccp(1024/2, 768/2);
[mainScene addChild:background];
```

RGBA4444 makes your images smaller but they won't look good when they have gradients. The default one is RGBA8888.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, i found this thread very helpful: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8142

for the source code: https://github.com/asinesio/cocos2d-PRKit